# Command not found when using a package installed with apt-get

Tags: bash, debian, package, apt-get

I'm used to apt-get however today I'm stuck by something really easy. I'm on a Debian 8 VM and need to use `gethostip`. As it's part of [syslinux](http://linux.die.net/man/1/gethostip) here is what I've done:

```
$ sudo apt-get install syslinux
$ gethostip -d localhost
```

However it returns me `bash: gethostip: command not found`. I also tried `which gethostip` to find the package and it returns nothing.

What should I do in order to make it works?

Comment: Oh yeah I also tried that but didn't tell in the commend, nothing shows up.

Comment: Also have a look at `dpkg -S gethostip` (and try to run `/usr/bin/gethostip`).

Comment: It returns `dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern *gethostip*`

Comment: Ok, then it does not seem to be installed.

Comment: The weird thing is that wen I'm doing `sudo apt-get install syslinux` again it returns `syslinux is already the newest version`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`gethostip` is *not* part of the `syslinux` binary package.

Debian chose to split *syslinux* (the source package) into multiple binary (== installable) packages, to allow people/dependencies to just install the components they need. E.g. if you don't want to create bootable CDs, chances are high that you won't need the `isolinux` package.

The package that contains `/usr/bin/gethostip` is called `syslinux-utils`.

You can use the [search on packages.debian.org](https://packages.debian.org/search?searchon=contents&keywords=%2Fusr%2Fbin%2Fgethostip&mode=path&suite=stable&arch=any) to find out, which package installs a given file.

Alternatively you could install the [`command-not-found` package](https://packages.debian.org/sid/command-not-found), that will suggest to you which package to install when you typed a yet-unknown command on the cmdline.